# Editar los datos de un usuario especifico con firebase en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Buenas estoy realizando un trabajo en firebase con android y quisiera saber como seria el código para editar los datos de un usuario; es decir, el usuario ingresa con su cuenta, ve sus datos y pulsa un botón que diga editar datos, ya sea su nombre, foto, contraseña, etc. Al momento que un usuario se registra lo hace con su correo y contraseña y también ingresa su nombre, celular, y esos datos se guarda en la base de datos de firebase y el correo y la contraseña en la autentificación de usuarios de firebase, la parte de mostrar los datos del usuario ya lo hice, solo quisiera saber como hago para que usuario pueda editar sus datos. Gracias

Aqui se guarda el usuario y la contraseña
[image: aqui se guarda el usuario y la contraseña]

Aqui se guarda los datos del usuario registrado
[image: aqui se guarda los datos del usuario registrado]

en este ejemplo se ve como muestra el nombre y la foto asociada a la cuenta de un usuario, también como modificar la foto del usuario, pero no como actualizar el nombre del usuario por uno nuevo

public class Main3Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
private TextView txtusu;
private Button btnatras;
private ImageView imgperfil;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

private DatabaseReference mDataBase;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

private int CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE = 1;
private StorageReference mStorage;

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);
}

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressDialog= new ProgressDialog(this);
    txtusu= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtusu);
    btnatras= (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnatras);
    imgperfil= (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgperfil);

    mStorage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    imgperfil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent();
            intent.setType("image/*");
            intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Seleccione una imagen de la galería"), CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE);
            }
        }
    });

    btnatras = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnatras);
    btnatras.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null)
                mAuth.signOut();
        }
    });

    mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null){
                mStorage= FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
                mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Alumnos");
                mDataBase.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        txtusu.setText(String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Usuario").getValue()));
                        String imageUrl=String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child("Foto_Perfil").getValue());
                        if (URLUtil.isValidUrl(imageUrl)){
                    Picasso.with(Main3Activity.this).load(Uri.parse(imageUrl)).into(imgperfil);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
            }else {
                startActivity(new Intent(Main3Activity.this, Main2Activity.class));
                finish();
            }
        }
    };
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null) {
            return;
        }
        progressDialog.setMessage("Cargando imagen...");
        progressDialog.show();
        final Uri uri = data.getData();
        if (uri == null) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            return;
        }
        if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() == null)
            return;
        if (mStorage == null)
            mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        if (mDataBase == null)
            mDataBase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Alumnos");

        final StorageReference filepath = mStorage.child("Foto_Perfil").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        final DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDataBase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
        currentUserDB.child("Foto_Perfil").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                String image = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();

                if (!image.equals("default") && !image.isEmpty()) {
                    Task<Void> task = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl(image).delete();
                    task.addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Imagen borrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Error, Imagen no borrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                currentUserDB.child("Foto_Perfil").removeEventListener(this);

                filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(Main3Activity.this, new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Uri downloadUri = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, "Finalizado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                        Picasso.with(Main3Activity.this).load(downloadUri).fit().centerCrop().into(imgperfil);
                        final DatabaseReference currentUserDB = mDataBase.child(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
                        currentUserDB.child("Foto_Perfil").setValue(downloadUri.toString());
                    }
                }).addOnFailureListener(Main3Activity.this, new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(Main3Activity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Bienvenido a SO en español. Es preciso que indiques lo que has intentando hasta ahora y qué errores estás teniendo. Si no sabes por donde empezar, lo primero sería revisar la documentación de Firebase al respecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Es fácil solo es de usar la misma referencia de tu base de datos:

```
String nuevoUsuario = "Miguel Angel";
mDataBase.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).child("Usuario").setValue(nuevoUsuario);
```

Recuerda donde **child()** ahí va el nombre de tu campo en la base de datos de firebase.

Bueno ese es una forma directa de como guardar cambios en firebase database, cuando usamos **setValue()**, este puede recibir varios tipos de datos, como enteros y hasta objetos ejeplo:

```
class usuario {
    private String Usuario;
    private String Foto_Perfil;
    //tu constructor default
    //agregas los getters  an setter para poder manejar el objeto
}



Usuario user = new Usuario();
user.setUsuario("Miguel angel");
user.setFoto_Perfil(".....");
mDataBase.child(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()).setValue(user);
```

Comment: vaya... era sencillo(soy nuevo en esto :D), gracias broth